# Es posible darle formato a la salida de un DIR en CMD?

Tags: windows, script, cmd, batch

Estoy necesitando realizar un Windows batch (Windows CMD) que lea el contenido de una carpeta, y genere un archivo de texto que contenga un listado donde para cada archivo se pueda ver: un secuencial con la posición del archivo en el listado , el nombre del archivo, su tamaño y su fecha de modificación.

Ejemplo:

1. Archivo.txt 120kb 26/10/2021 10:00 a.m.
2. prueba.pdf 1100kb 10/10/2021 08:10 a.m.
3. datos.xls 10kb 09/08/2019 05:14 p.m.
4. fotos.png 23kb 07/11/2020 01:23 a.m.

Así sucesivamente con los archivos de un directorio especifico.

La verdad no se si esto sea posible.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la instrucción de CMD [ForFiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles)

```
forfiles /C "cmd /c echo @FILE @FSIZE @FDATE @FTIME >> salida.txt"
```

`forfiles` recorre los archivos en el directorio se puede especificar cuál directorio usando `/P <pathname>` usas el parámetro `/C <command>` para especificar el comando a correr en cada archivo en este caso se usa el comando `echo` para mandar a la salida las propiedades que buscas `@FILE @FSIZE @FDATE @FTIME` y mandas esa salida a un archivo usando `>>` (un append) al archivo donde quieres guardar tus resultados

Comment: Mil gracias, funciona muy bien!!!